# calculating the euclidean dist between each row of a dataframe with all other rows in another dataframe, but out put should be which row

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I have similar situation as this one: 
[calculating the euclidean dist between each row of a dataframe with all other rows in another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231773/calculating-the-euclidean-dist-between-each-row-of-a-dataframe-with-all-other-ro)

So, I have two dataframes, x and y. I want to calculate euclidean dist between each row of x and each row of y, but I am interested to get for each row of x WHICH row of y has the minimal distance, because I want to cluster rows of x according to distances to rows of y (x has e.g. 10 rows, and y, e.g. 4 rows).
So my output should be like this:
1 2 2 4 3 3 2 2 1 4
that is, the first row of x is closest to the first row of y, and so on.
I am writing algorithm for kmeans clustering.
I'm pretty new to R and could use some help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted solution to the problem you posted is this:

```
unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(y)), function(i) min(sqrt(colSums((y[i, ] - t(x))^2)))))
```

To change this to get the index instead of the value, you change `min` to `which.min` and that should return the output you are looking for:

```
unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(y)), function(i) which.min(sqrt(colSums((y[i, ] - t(x))^2)))))
```

Comment: Your indices refer to the elements of the second data frame `y` saying which element of the first data frame `x` is closest to the first, second, ... element of the `y`. I think it should be the other way round. One could just switch the data frames